# Can i install haproxy on the same server of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, haproxy

I'm reading and preparing to create HA Postgresql cluster of 3 servers using patrnoi , etcd , haproxy and keeplived.

My question is - Is it ok to install HAProxy on the same servers of Postgres , or it is a must to have it on a dedicated servers ?